# ADF input text enable when check box is checked

Tags: oracle-adf

i am New to ADF, i want display/enable the input  text box when checkbox is checked and i should disable when it is unchecked below is the check box ADF code,

**ADF Code:**

```
<af:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Apply WITSML Filter" id="sbc11"
autoSubmit="true" contentStyle="margin-left:10px;" valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.welljobs_bean.applyWITSMLFilterIndicator}"/>
```

**Bean:**

```
private transient RichSelectBooleanCheckbox applyWITSMLFilterIndicator;
    public void setapplyWITSMLFilterIndicator(RichSelectBooleanCheckbox applyWITSMLFilterIndicator) {
        this.applyWITSMLFilterIndicator= applyWITSMLFilterIndicator;
    }

    public RichSelectBooleanCheckbox getapplyWITSMLFilterIndicator() {
        return applyWITSMLFilterIndicator;
    }
```

**The input text i want to show:**

```
 <af:inputText id="it140" autoComplete="off"
 binding="#{pageFlowScope.welljobs_bean.applyWITSMLFilterIndicator.curvesFilter}"
 dimensionsFrom="content" editable="inherit" rendered="true"/>
```

**Bean:**

```
 private transient RichInputText curvesFilter;
        public void setCurvesFilter(RichInputText curvesFilter) {
            this.curvesFilter = curvesFilter;
        }
        public RichInputText getCurvesFilter() {
            return curvesFilter;
        }
```

Can anybody please help?
it is also  giving me javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'curvesFilter'.   Exception

Comment: Can you add you jsf checkbox code and associated java bean ?

Comment: i have added them to question kindly check them

Comment: Can you also add the inputText jsf that you want to change ? I'll show you on your code it's easier

Comment: i have added them to question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with EL Expression, partial trigger/autosubmit and ValueChangeEvent.

You want to save the boolean value of the checkedbox inside your bean so you can render or disable the inputText when this value change inside your valueChangeEventListener.

You then want to refresh the inputText so it will display it's new render/disable value by adding the following property to the inputText parent :

```
partialTriggers="sbc11"
```

partialTriggers refresh the whole content of a container when an action occur on the element id you give him.

Assuming you want to disable/enable the inputText :

Bean :

```
public boolean checkboxIsChecked = false; //or private with getter and setter
public void checkBoxValueChange(ValueChangeEvent ve){
    this.checkboxIsChecked = ve.getNewValue();
}
```

Jsf :

```
<af:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Apply WITSML Filter" id="sbc11"
autoSubmit="true" contentStyle="margin-left:10px;" valueChangeListener="#
{pageFlowScope.welljobs_bean.checkBoxValueChange}"/>

...

 <af:inputText id="it140" autoComplete="off"
 binding="#{pageFlowScope.welljobs_bean.applyWITSMLFilterIndicator.curvesFilter}"
 dimensionsFrom="content" disabled="#{pageFlowScope.welljobs_bean.checkboxIsChecked}"/>
```

don't forget to add the partialTriggers="CHECKBOXID" to the inputText parent container

For official example see documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/web.1111/b31973/af_lifecycle.htm#CIAHCFJF

Comment: How to do same for this corresponding <af:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Apply WITSML Filter"
                                                id="sbc11" autoSubmit="true" contentStyle="margin-left:10px;"
                                                valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.welljobs_bean.applyWITSMLFilterIndicator}"/>

Comment: @SaiCharan Just add the checkBoxValueChange to your bean and change the valueChangeListener to be valueChangeListener="#
{pageFlowScope.welljobs_bean.checkBoxValueChange}" as i described in the answer

Comment: Didn't get you, can you please elaborate this?

Comment: @SaiCharan I gave you the code to do this with your af:selectBooleanCheckbox in the answer, what don't you understand ?

Comment: @SaiCharan I added a link to the official documentation regarding this topic